# Override styled-components in React

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to find a way to override a styled component with styled-components like this:

Let's say I have a reusable component Wrapper:

```
class Wrapper extends Component {

  ...

  render() {
    const Wrap = styled.div`
      padding: 5px;
      background-color: green;
    `;
    return (
       <Wrap>
         {children}
       </Wrap>
    )
  }
}

export default Wrapper
```

And then I have Component B that imports Wrapper but should extend the styles like this: *myNewWrap uses Wrapper*

```
import Wrapper from './Wrapper'

class B extends Component {

  ...

  render() {
    const myNewWrap = styled(Wrapper)`
      background-color: red;
    `;
    return (
       <myNewWrap>
         Some awesome text
       </myNewWrap>
    )
  }
}
```

Result should be that *Some awesome text* has padding from Wrapper but background-color from own component. But what I get is only the styles from Wrapper.

Comment: please check using chrome inspector that your class B has the style of padding or not & if it is then use padding: 5px !important instead of padding: 5px; in your wrapper class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using `extend` from Styled-Components? `Styled` generates new component styles with a new class whereas `extend` is meant to use base styling from another Styled component, but then tweak or add additional styles.

Additionally, their docs explain when you should you use `styled()` (see section "When should I use `styled()`?")
[when to use styled](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/faqs#when-should-i-use-styled)

Answer (score 0):

you override the styled component simply by passing a className to the styled component and do styling with reference to that class

```
<myNewWrap className="my-wrap">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the specificity by adding `&` multiple times (which gets replaced by the class name):

```js
const NewWrap = styled(Wrapper)`
  && {
    /* overriding styles here */
  }
`
```

Or for certain cases use `!important`.